# Ubuntu 16.04 Server preseed - Partitioning: Use entire disk

Tags: ubuntu, preseed

I am trying to generate a semi-automated Ubuntu installation. However I am running in some issues with the preseed file with regards to partitioning.

What I would like to happen is:

- skip the menu where user would normally specify Guided (with all the different variants)
  or Manual partitioning
- Ask the user which disk to be used (in case we have more than one disk)
- Use a partition recipe specified within the preseed

Currently what I have is:

```
    ### Partitioning


# In addition, you'll need to specify the method to use.
# The presently available methods are:
# - regular: use the usual partition types for your architecture
# - lvm:     use LVM to partition the disk
# - crypto:  use LVM within an encrypted partition
d-i partman-auto/method string regular

d-i partman-auto/init_automatically_partition select Guided - use entire disk

# If one of the disks that are going to be automatically partitioned
# contains an old LVM configuration, the user will normally receive a
# warning. This can be preseeded away...
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
# The same applies to pre-existing software RAID array:
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
# And the same goes for the confirmation to write the lvm partitions.
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true

# You can choose one of the three predefined partitioning recipes:
# - atomic: all files in one partition
# - home:   separate /home partition
# - multi:  separate /home, /usr, /var, and /tmp partitions
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic

d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string             \
        1 1 1 free                                \
            $bios_boot{ }                         \
            method{ biosgrub }                    \
        .                                         \
        256 40 256 fat32                          \
            $primary{ }                           \
            $lvmignore{ }                         \
            method{ efi }                         \
            format{ }                             \
        .                                         \
        4096 4096 4096 linux-swap                 \
            method{ swap } format{ }              \
        .                                         \
        100 10000 100000000 ext4                  \
            $primary{ }                           \
            method{ format } format{ }            \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }  \
            mountpoint{ / }                       \
        .
# This makes partman automatically partition without confirmation.
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish

# Ask user if existing partitions need to be removed!
d-i partman/confirm boolean false
d-i partman-md/confirm boolean false
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean false
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean false
d-i partman-md/confirm_nooverwrite boolean false
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean false
```

The problem with this preseed is that, even though I have specified "select Guided - use entire disk", it still uses the first disk and only the available remaining free space on that Disk, instead of using the entire disk.

Does anyone have a clue how I can solve the issue?

Thank you.